# Get metadata of Office 365 Service Communications API through odata.context Url

Tags: c#, odata, office365api

I am trying to get the metadata from Office 365 Management APIs. When I a make a call to the following Url

```
resource = "https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/tenant-id/ServiceComms/Messages"
```

I get the response and in the content, I have the following information (I have replaced the tenant GUID with name):

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://office365servicecomms-prod.cloudapp.net/api/v1.0/tenant-id/$metadata#Messages",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Office365ServiceComms.ExposedContracts.Message",
      "@odata.id": "https://office365servicecomms-prod.cloudapp.net/api/v1.0/tenant-id/Messages('LY177449')",
      "@odata.editLink": "https://office365servicecomms-prod.cloudapp.net/api/v1.0/tenant-id/Messages('LY177449')",
      "AffectedWorkloadDisplayNames@odata.type": "#Collection(String)",
      "AffectedWorkloadDisplayNames": [],
      "AffectedWorkloadNames@odata.type": "#Collection(String)",
      "AffectedWorkloadNames": [
```

From the response I assumed that I can retrieve metadata from `https://office365servicecomms-prod.cloudapp.net/api/v1.0/tenant-id/$metadata`

But when I make an auth call to that Url I just get an Internal server error msg

```
string resource =
    "https://office365servicecomms-prod.cloudapp.net/api/v1.0/tenant-id/$metadata";
using(HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authResult.AccessToken);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(resource);
}
```

In `httpClient`, I have 2 headers, the `Authorization: bearer token` (which works fine) and `Accept: application/json`

In `HttpResponseMessage response`, I get a `500 Internal Server Error`. There is no other information.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Does anyone know how to get the metadata from Office 365 Service Communications API?

Comment: Have you had a look at the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference#get-current-status

Comment: You should also take a look at the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/odata_standards/ms-odatajson/1259ce6b-273d-4c01-9e79-48a0be630f39

Comment: I would suggest you inspect the content of the response to see if it provides any additional information. When I test you sample URL I get a null reference exception which was expected since I do not have a tenant id.

Comment: I followed the official docs, I will update the question with response

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you inspect the content of the response to see if it provides any additional information.

For example

> When the service encounters an error, it reports the error response
>   code to the caller, using standard HTTP error-code syntax. As per
>   OData V4 specification, additional information is included in the body
>   of the failed call as a single JSON object. The following is an
>   example of a full JSON error body:

```
{ 
    "error":{ 
        "code":"AF5000.  An internal server error occurred.",
        "message": "Retry the request." 
    } 
}
```

Reference [Office 365 Service Communications API reference (Preview): Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference#errors)

When I test your sample URL

```
https://office365servicecomms-prod.cloudapp.net/api/v1.0/tenant-id/$metadata#CurrentStatus
```

I get a null reference exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiFilterProvider.GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__75`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.<RemoveDuplicates>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__75`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.InitializeFilterPipeline()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.GetFilterGrouping()
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Office365ServiceComms.MessageHandlers.RequestResponseLogHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

which was to be expected since I do not have a tenant id nor auth token.

And since this API is in preview then it could very well be an actual problem/bug on their side. Should consider raising an issue if they have that ability available.

When I test the [odata examples at odata.org](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/understand-odata-in-6-steps/), calling the `odata.context` returns the schema from their example as expected.

Comment: I have written on there offical github but no response yet.

Comment: I was looking at the ans of this question and he mentioned about getting the schema. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fc2ac9fb-2816-4a0b-a759-06cb2faf6790/how-to-filter-message-center-messages-in-quotoffice-365-service-communications-apiquot-to-get

Comment: In response I only get 500 Internal error. I cant find the body of the failed call